# How do I execute a program from Python? os.system fails due to spaces in path

Tags: python, shellexecute

I have a Python script that needs to execute an external program, but for some reason fails.

If I have the following script:

```
import os;
os.system("C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe");
raw_input();
```

Then it fails with the following error:

> 'C:\Temp\a' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I escape the program with quotes:

```
import os;
os.system('"C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe"');
raw_input();
```

Then it works. However, if I add a parameter, it stops working again:

```
import os;
os.system('"C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe" "C:\\test.txt"');
raw_input();
```

What is the right way to execute a program and wait for it to complete? I do not need to read output from it, as it is a visual program that does a job and then just exits, but I need to wait for it to complete.

Also note, moving the program to a non-spaced path is not an option either.

---

This does not work either:

```
import os;
os.system("'C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe'");
raw_input();
```

Note the swapped single/double quotes.

With or without a parameter to Notepad here, it fails with the error message

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

[`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) will avoid problems with having to deal with quoting conventions of various shells. It accepts a list, rather than a string, so arguments are more easily delimited. i.e.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe', 'C:\\test.txt'])
```

Comment: It is much simpler to use raw string in windows: r"C:\Temp\a b c\Notepad.exe"

Comment: Another option may or may not be to use the exec* functions which are also in sys from memory. They take an array in a similar fashion, but I don't think they ever return. Not sure about the semantics here, I recall it mentioned overwriting the current process though, so...

Comment: Yes, the os.exec* functions will replace the current process, so your python process won't continue.  They're used more on unix where the general method for a shell to launch a command is to fork() and then exec() in the child.

Comment: The windows method for this is the os.spawn family, which could be used instead.  subprocess is more portable though, and offers more flexibility in controlling the process (capturing input/output etc), so is preferred.

Comment: @PierreBdr: There is a case where rawstrings won't work: where you need a trailing slash. eg r'c:\foo\bar\'.  Actually, its probably better to use forward slashes instead.  These are accepted throughout the windows API (though not always by some shell commands (eg copy))

Comment: *Yes, the os.exec* functions will replace the current process* - not on Windows; see http://bugs.python.org/issue9148#msg109179

Comment: I tried the same solution but I am getting OSERRoR: Permission denied

Comment: For python >= 3.5 `subprocess.call` should be replaced by `subprocess.run`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api

Answer (score 91):

Here's a different way of doing it.

If you're using Windows the following acts like double-clicking the file in Explorer, or giving the file name as an argument to the DOS "start" command: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its extension is associated with.

```
filepath = 'textfile.txt'
import os
os.startfile(filepath)
```

Example:

```
import os
os.startfile('textfile.txt')
```

This will open textfile.txt with Notepad if Notepad is associated with .txt files.

Comment: Is there an equivalent function for *nix systems?

Comment: @Romeno: you could try: `webbrowser.open("textfile.txt")` it should open a text editor. See also [*"start the second program wholly on its own, as though I just 'double-clicked on it'."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13078786/4279)

Answer (score 37):

The outermost quotes are consumed by Python itself, and the Windows shell doesn't see it. As mentioned above, Windows only understands double-quotes. 
Python will convert forward-slashed to backslashes on Windows, so you can use

```
os.system('"C://Temp/a b c/Notepad.exe"')
```

The ' is consumed by Python, which then passes "C://Temp/a b c/Notepad.exe" (as a Windows path, no double-backslashes needed) to CMD.EXE

Comment: This seems the best in a scenario like `os.system('curl URL > file')` where I want to see cURL's progress meter refresh for really big files.

Comment: If the first letter after a backslash has special meaning (i.e. `\t`, `\n`, etc.) then that particular backslash must be doubled.  Being a Windows path has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Note that if you use `os.system()` on Windows the cmd window will open and remain open until you close the process that it started. IMHO it's better to use `os.startfile()`.

Comment: Don't forget `import os`

Answer (score 21):

At least in Windows 7 and Python 3.1, `os.system` in Windows wants the command line *double-quoted* if there are spaces in path to the command. For example:

```
  TheCommand = '\"\"C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe\"\"'
  os.system(TheCommand)
```

A real-world example that was stumping me was cloning a drive in VirtualBox. The `subprocess.call` solution above didn't work because of some access rights issue, but when I double-quoted the command, `os.system` became happy:

```
  TheCommand = '\"\"C:\\Program Files\\Sun\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe\" ' \
                 + ' clonehd \"' + OrigFile + '\" \"' + NewFile + '\"\"'
  os.system(TheCommand)
```

Comment: That was it! I'd go for `subprocess`, but sometimes `os.system` and `os.popen(...).read()` are just faster to type. BTW, you don't need to escape double quotes inside single, i.e. `'""C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe""'` will do.

Answer (score 17):

For python >= 3.5 `subprocess.run` should be used in place of `subprocess.call`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['notepad.exe', 'test.txt'])
```

Answer (score 12):

```
import win32api # if active state python is installed or install pywin32 package seperately

try: win32api.WinExec('NOTEPAD.exe') # Works seamlessly
except: pass
```

Comment: and it seems no quoting is needed with this method, eg
win32api.WinExec('pythonw.exe d:\web2py\web2py.py -K welcome') starts the web2py scheduler in the background.

Comment: @rahul and does it except arguments for the executable? So if you want Notepad to open a file or is that seperate?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it's the same problem as when you use shortcuts in Windows... Try this:

```
import os
os.system("\"C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe\" C:\\test.txt")
```

Comment: sorry, that does not work either, edited question to reflect this.

Comment: I think windows only uses ", rather than ' for quoting.  This will probably work if you change this.  However you'll still run into problems with if you have embedded quotes etc.

Comment: I thought it took both, but you're probably right. I know it works (in the shell atleast) with double quotes.

Comment: +1 this is the best one, windows XP, 2007 home edition worked nicely

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.7, use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module). Use raw string to simplify the Windows paths:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'C:\Temp\Example\Notepad.exe', 'C:\test.txt'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to run your Django web server (in Linux) that there is space between your path (path=`'/home/<you>/<first-path-section> <second-path-section>'`), so do the following:

```
import subprocess

args = ['{}/manage.py'.format('/home/<you>/<first-path-section> <second-path-section>'), 'runserver']
res = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error_ = res.communicate()

if not error_:
    print(output)
else:
    print(error_)
```

---

[**Note**]:

- Do not forget accessing permission: `chmod 755 -R <'yor path'>`
- `manage.py` is exceutable: `chmod +x manage.py`

Answer (score 0):

No need for sub-process, It can be simply achieved by

```
GitPath="C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe"# Application File Path in mycase its GITBASH
os.startfile(GitPath)
```