# How to execute a shell command through Python

Tags: python, shell

I am new to Python programming. I want to execute a shell command "at" from a Python program. Can any one of the Python gurus help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module can be used for this purpose:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["at", "x", "y", "z"])
```

Replace `x`, `y` and `z` with the parameters to `at`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, rather than using subprocess.call(), you could use Popen to capture the output of the command (rather than the return code).

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['at','x','y','z'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

This may not be relevant to the at command, but it is useful to know. The same can be done with the stdin and stderr. Look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

use search. already answered: [How do I execute a program from python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path)

Comment: However, du to this question being asked years later, the solutions differ. Additionally, this question is not about spaces and possibly not about Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.check_output` appears to be the canonical convenience function in Python 2.4+ for executing a command and inspecting the output. It also raises an error if the command returns a non-zero value (indicating an error).

Like `subprocess.call`, `check_output` is a convenience wrapper around `subprocess.Popen`, so you may prefer using `Popen` directly. But convenience wrappers are ...convenient, in theory.