# How do I execute two programs from python at the same time?

Tags: python

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path) explains how to launch a single external program from Python
How shall I launch multipal programs(or threads) at the same time ?

My intended application is a video slide show. I want to launch a image sequence player and a music player at the same time

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try calling it more than once?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: `subprocess.call` blocks until the subprocess completes.

Comment: `subprocess.popen` doesn't & is what I've used in the past to launch multiple proceses.

Comment: @user488551: you mean `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` doesn't block unless you explicitly ask it to by calling `communicate` on the returned object, so you can call it more than once to start more than one process.

If you do need to communicate with both sub-processes simultaneously (read their STDOUT, for instance), then invoke `subprocess.Popen` in separate threads. Each thread can manage a sub-process and communicate with it. Naturally, this leaves you to do all the synchronization but that highly depends on your specific application.