# Python How to open filepath with spaces when passing through formatter

Tags: python

How can I run a command that requires a filepath that contains spaces when using the `start` command with `os.system`

For Example:

```
# path_d[key] = C:\Users\John\Documents\Some File With Space.exe
path = path_d[key]
os.system("start {0}".format(path))
```

When I try running it I end up getting an error saying:

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\Users\John\Documents\Some.'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [os.system to invoke an exe which lies in a dir whose name contains whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977215/os-system-to-invoke-an-exe-which-lies-in-a-dir-whose-name-contains-whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly escape your special characters in `path`, which might be easily done as such:

```
path = r"C:\Users\John\Documents\Some File With Space.exe"
```

To execute it under Windows:

```
import os

os.system(r"C:\Users\John\Documents\Some File With Space.exe")
```

**EDIT**

per request of OP:

```
path_dict = {"path1": r"C:\Users\John\Documents\Some File With Space.exe"}
os.system('{}'.format(path_dict["path1"]))
```

Comment: How could I make it if the filepath is stored as a dictionary and not hardcoded?

Comment: @InAFlash I added (edited) the post including the way I execute it and it works fine under python2 on my machine

Answer (score 1):

i do the following

```
path = path_d[key]
os.system(r'start "{0}"'.format(path))
```

so, surround the path with double quotes. that way it will take care of spaces in path.
if there is no default application to open, it might open command prompt. So, if its a text file do the following

```
os.system(r'notepad "{0}"'.format(path))
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to result in opening a command prompt with the title as the path name

Comment: if its an exe, you directly give path to the exe instead of putting start infornt of it

Comment: I found that `os.system(r'start "random title" "{0}"'.format(path))` worked well. MS-DOS 'start' command expects a title for the first argument if you use quotations.

Comment: @Sam, looks like its already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977215/os-system-to-invoke-an-exe-which-lies-in-a-dir-whose-name-contains-whitespace

Comment: It seems the question you linked doesn't include the use of "start" call. I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Did you atleast try the same command from command line and see what's happening.because..when I used start with a text file it did open a new command prompt

Comment: When I use the start command you provided it would open a command prompt and did not start the file with the default application. When I use the command i specified in comment above starts the file. The command you provided opens a command prompt with the title as the path specified. I was able to see arguments of start command here: https://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm

Comment: Just wondering..usually it's better to use subprocess modules popen function. Do you want to try that?