# How to pass the commands, with the spaces in folder names, through python scripts to run on CMD prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

1. Get the file path.

   ```
   ATPPath = self.fl_ctrl.GetPath()
   ```
2. Add the file path in command

   ```
   Command=  some commands in double quotes + ATPPath
   ```
3. Pass the command to run on CMD prompt

   ```
   os.system(Command)
   ```

While running the above command it is breaking at spaces present in the folder name in the path.

Input path =>

```
D:\R-TOOL_SVN\input files\4.1.5-TRANSITION_ALTITUDES-Transition_Altitudes-Half_Bank-ATP.yml
```

Expected output path =>

```
D:\R-TOOL_SVN\"input files"\4.1.5-TRANSITION_ALTITUDES-Transition_Altitudes-Half_Bank-ATP.yml
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.system to invoke an exe which lies in a dir whose name contains whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977215/os-system-to-invoke-an-exe-which-lies-in-a-dir-whose-name-contains-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want, if I understand correctly, is a way to pass a file path as an argument to a function. In order to do this, you need to escape the spaces. Try something like this:

```py
filepath.replace(" ", "\ ")
```