# Python script to run an exe-file on all files in a directory

Tags: python, loops, exe, subdirectory

I have a small .exe file that I'd like to run on all files in a given directory. It is launched as follows "./myprogram.exe file" and converts my files into a different data type.

Now I want to build a python script, that runs this exe on all files in a given directory, including all subdirectories. I am totally new to python, so I have no clue how to do this.

Does anyone have suggestions how to do this? Do I need python or any other script language in the first place?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a linux box, I would have told you to use a `find` call, but the `.exe` seems to tell you are on windows.

In python, you should use something like this

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
   for name in files:
      subprocess.call(["path_to_your_programm/myprogram.exe", os.path.join(root, name)]
```

Comment: I also have a linux version of my converter. So I can use the "find" call to find all desired files and execute my converter on it?

Comment: @fox : yes, a `find . -exec myprogram {} \;` should do the stuff

Answer (score 1):

For a match of all files from a directory + sub directories, take a look at: [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

To call your program, take a look at : [How do I execute a program from python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify the example in the python docs for [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to do that.

To actually call your external program, you can use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call).