# python concatenate files using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, concatenation

I have been searching and although I find long and complicated (many features I do not need) on how to just simply have python have linux use the cat function to concatenate files to a single file.

From my reading apparently subprocess is the way to do this.
Here is what I have but obviously does not work :(

```
subprocess.call("cat", str(myfilelist[0]), str(myfilelist[1]), str(myfilelist[2]), str(myfilelist[3]), ">", "concatinatedfile.txt"])
```

the above assumes:

```
myfilelist[]
```

the above list has 4 filenames + paths as a list; for example one item in the list is "mypath/myfile1.txt"

I would take non subprocess (but simple) methods also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `>`  is a shell function you need to do `shell=True`

`subprocess.call("echo hello world > some.txt",shell=True)` ... works in windows at least

alternatively you can do somethign like

```
with open("redirected_output.txt") as f:
    subprocess.call("/home/bin/cat some_file.txt",stdout=f)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use cat and redirection > you must call a shell, for example via system:

```
from os import system
system("cat a.txt b.txt > c.txt")
```

However you must pay attention to code injection.

Comment: coolz! this worked faster. so what is the difference of using subprocess then?

Comment: good answer(+1) i just did the same thing with subprocess

Comment: here you are running a shell so it is slower and more prone to security risks

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files).  His solution seems to be concise and easy to understand, I'll post it here:

```
filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', ...]
with open('path/to/output/file', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan. THis does work, and I had seen it. It is just that it is CPU intensive when you have text files each over 10k or more lines :( I wanted to use the faster cat function of linux.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/dimo414/2993381) seems to be some really optimized concatenation @StudentOfScience

Comment: I just ran it with my big files, took 1 min 34 sec. When I use cat manually (minus me typing the code) it take 24 sec. that is why. Not that I do not have an additional 1 min and 10 sec to give, but just as a learning opportunity to use subprocess, or python to linux I asked the question. Thx.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9882548/2502012) would help you with your learning opportunity to use subprocess for concatenation