# How to run python script from python with different interpreter version?

Tags: python

How to run my script with one version of python from script with another version of python?
Also, is there a way to catch all outputs of my script and print it?

Comment: You should only ask one question per, ehm, question.

Comment: Not sure I understand your second question. The output of your script is already being printed. If it wasn't, it wouldn't be called output.

Comment: Take a look at the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Answer to the first question: Depends on the environment(Windows,Linux, etc). Answer to the second: print statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to theoretically run say a script with python2 from a script running with python3? (Or something like that, I'm not really sure) If so I would use subprocess. You can find more information on that https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html and [How do I execute a program from python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path).

```
#my python3 script
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python2", "python2scipt.py"])
```

Comment: Better use `subprocess.call(["python2", "python2script.py"])` - each part of command line call being one item in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me: `output = subprocess.Popen(p,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]`

Comment: Oops, you're right I did forget those are necessary when using subprocesses. Thanks for the catch. I've corrected my example.