# Execute a Windows path with spaces in Python

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to build a program that mimics the 'run' feature of Windows in a Windows environment. Now I know that sounds a bit silly, but we are on 'limited' computers, and the cmd is completely locked so we don't have any choice but to build our own program files for our needs.

Specifically, what I am trying to do is a little utility that will ask for the drive, subject, and course number, and based on that open the full path.

> i.e. W Python 47 -> w://courses/subjects/python/classes/47 - Arrays & Pointers

I have done most of the work in Python and reached the last stage where I need to get the full path based only on the number with the code being something like:

```
os.system(start 'drive + '://courses/subjects/' + subject + '/classes/' + class')
```

Where drive, subject, and class are variables that hold the data of the current path.

The problem is that when there is a space in the file path, Windows can't find it, and produces an error.

The simple solution would be to put double quotes, but for some reason double quotes on the start command is considered as a cmd command which is blocked..

Any ideas on a workaround, or maybe Python is not the way to go, and so any ideas on a different language, that would be easier. (I have basic knowledge in C++, Python, Java)

p.s. This is not the exact code, that I am using, I will post that tomorrow.

Comment: Why are you tagging completely unrelated entities such as Java and C++?  Best to limit your question to one language, else it will appear to be (and in fact will be) too broad. Edit: I've removed those tags for you.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path

Comment: You might find subprocess is easier to use https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument after `start` is the name of the newly created command prompt window, and the second and third should be the path to the application and its parameters, respectively.

```
start "" "c:\path with spaces\app.exe" param1 "param with spaces"
```

If you want to use `os.system`, you could try:

```
norm_path = os.path.normpath("{0}://courses/subjects/{1}/classes/{2}".format (drive, subject, class_name))
os.system('start "" "' + norm_path + '"')
```

But I would probably use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
norm_path = os.path.normpath("{0}://courses/subjects/{1}/classes/{2}".format (drive, subject, class_name))
os.startfile( norm_path )
```

**Please note**: you should not use a variable named `class`.

Comment: Actually one *cannot* use a variable named `class`. It's a keyword.