# How do I open an an excel file in Microsoft Excel by runnning a command in python?

Tags: python

I want to open an excel file in Microsoft excel, and I don't want to do it using a mouse click but rather a python code. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open external programs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238645/how-to-open-external-programs-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile)

```
import os, subprocess
os.startfile(r'filepath') #For windows only
subprocess.call(['open', 'filepath']) #For MAC only
```