# Can I tell Python to execute command line in cmd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, cmd, windows-7

I'm working on a personal project as a very amateur programmer and to do this, I need to have python tell cmd to run an external program via command line.

For example, I need to `chdir ("C:\blah\blah")` on Python, and run
`externalprogram -w "<destination>\newName.fileType>" "<source>\*.*"`.

I'm very lost in how to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far my code looks like this

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\Program Files (x86)\<externalProgram>')
os.system('<externalCommand> "<destination>\file.fileType" "<source>\*.*"')
```

Still can't get it to work though no errors are being posted to the shell.

Comment: Usually you can use [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) `import subprocess;
subprocess.call(['C:\blah\blah\newName.fileType'])`, [How do I execute a program from python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path)

Comment: You might want the effect of `chdir` to last/be upon your python process/script  - [os.chdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir)?

Comment: Would you "accept" the preferred answer below? You may accept your own if you wish. To accept, click on the tick mark adjacent to the answer you prefer. Please consider upvoting any others that you thought were helpful; this is not mandatory, but it is nice to do so. Finally I see that Prune's answer is not replied to - please consider making a response to everyone if you can.

Comment: Downvoted, see above. Happy to undownvote if you can click the tickmark.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
import os
os.system('your command')
```

Comment: I tried this and my cmd flashed open and closed and nothing moved. How could I check what the issue is?

Comment: @Hallquist If you are trying to execute `os.system('chdir your/dir')`, then it will not have any effect. It opens cmd changes directory in it and closes. If you want to change working directory for current python script then you might want to use `os.chdir('your/dir')` (as @greybeard suggested)

Comment: I tried and updated my post. I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need the **os.system()** method, near the bottom of [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).  You pass the command you want to run as a string.

Also, many UNIX system commands are built into this package; you might find the one you want as a specific call.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks?

```
os.system('<command> "<destination>\file.fileType" "<source>\*.*") #still in quote
```

starts with ' ends in "

```
os.system('<command> "<destination>\file.fileType" "<source>\*.*" ') #closed properly
```

If you don't want quotations in python to be recognised in quotes put a backslash in front

```
print (" \" ") # prints out "
```

say add parameters to the command

```
destination = "folder\file.fileType"
source = "source\*.*"
os.system('<command> \" ' + destination + ' \" '+ source+' \" ') #closed
```

Comment: So, I've got it to print how I wanted, but am unable to get it to do anything. It just flashes and nothing happens. It seems I can't change the directory properly and it stays on user\pthyon. How could I make it run 2 or more commands in succession in the same cmd window?

Comment: import os
os.chdir('C:\Program Files (x86)')
os.system("cd")
os.system("PAUSE")

Answer (score 0):

So, my main issues were not adding the /D when for my directory change to change the disk as well, and the use of the '&&'.

```
import os
changeDir = ('cd /D C:\\Program Files (x86)\\externalProgram')
externalCommand = '<Command> \"<destination>\\newName.fileType\" \"<source>\\*.*\"'
os.system(changeDir + ' && ' externalCommand)
```