# how to run a python code from another python code

Tags: python, subprocess

I have multiple python codes in different folders which have to run in a sequence. There are similar questions asked before but, the answers do not seem to work out. i have tried the following commands:

```
subprocess.check_call(["Python", "D:/demo/full_alg.py"])
subprocess.check_output(["Python", "D:/demo/full_alg.py"])
os.system("D:/demo/full_alg.py")
```

That full_alg.py file, when executed must print out a list of files on which the code was executed and create corresponding tiff files

Comment: try by adding a `/` in front of  `"D:/demo..."` like `/D:/demo/....`

Comment: no that didnt work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Comment: Following this method [My answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path/48382727#48382727)

Comment: @rao I update my answer, hope help you up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` library such as below:

```
import subprocess

args = ['{}/manage.py'.format('/home/<you>/<path>'), 'runserver']
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Follow this method: [My answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path/48382727#48382727)

---

[UPDATE]:

This is an example with python3:

```
import subprocess

python_version = '3'
path_to_run = './'
py_name = '__main__.py'

# args = [f"python{python_version}", f"{path_to_run}{py_name}"]  # Available in python3
args = ["python{}".format(python_version), "{}{}".format(path_to_run, py_name)]

res = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error_ = res.communicate()

if not error_:
    print(output)
else:
    print(error_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you are not trying to import `full_alg.py` package and based on the function calls in main consume the results of the call. How to precisely do it depends strongly on the contents of `full_alg.py` though.

If you insist on running a subprocess which runs another python script I suggest looking at `multiprocessing` module and the examples [here](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html).

The reasons why your code does not work may be `Python` interpreter missing from `PATH`. I would suggest passing the full path to both the interpreter you are using and the script. This should do in case of running a `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.check_output`. For the last one (`os.system`) I don't think it can run unless you set up python interpreter to be the default application for opening `*.py` files and even then it depends on the non-obvious configuration of the OS to run.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that module but the examples define a function and then call the function in the main.  I would like to know how do I call python script externally and execute it?