# I'm trying to open a file via python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to open a file via my python project, but it doesn't work.. Is there any reason why?

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def openfile():

   window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="Open file", filetypes=(("exe files", "*.exe"),("all files", "*.*"))
    file_opener = open(window.filename)
    file_opener.read()

Button = Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)
Button.pack()
```

Comment: What is your error message? There are lots of things missing here, like missing import statements, no mainloop(), etc. You need to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that, I've changed it

Answer (score 1):

This code below just gets the content of the file.

```py
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *


window = Tk()

def openfile():
    window.filename = askopenfilename(title="Open file",
                                      filetypes=(("exe files", "*.exe"),
                                      ("all files", "*.*")))
    data = ""
    try:
        with open(window.filename) as f:
            data = f.read()
    except:
        pass

Button = Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)
Button.pack()
```

The line

> `data = f.read()`

Stores the content of the file in `data`. That’s all.
**Then, if you want to run this file, you can do this:**

### 1. Use [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

If you want to open / run the `.exe` file, use `os.system` like that:

```py
import os
os.system(window.filename)
```

This code acts like, for example on Windows, if you open a command prompt and type `[the file path]` -- It runs the file

### 2. Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

According to [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path/204049#204049), you can type this to run `filename`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(filename)
```

You can also go to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python?rq=1/89243#89243) (possible duplicate)