# Am I using os.system correctly? My application won't open anymore

Tags: python, os.system

A few days ago I had the line `os.system(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI")` in my program. I tested it and it worked fine, it opened the application just like I wanted it to.

Now, I'm coming back to it about five days later and all of a sudden it's not working properly. I checked the processes and it says `'C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

I have already looked at the other questions about os.system like [How do I execute a program from Python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path), but I am already using a raw string like one of the answers suggested. I don't understand how it can work one day, and the next it fails to work with no change to it.

Comment: You should probably replace `os.system` with `subprocess.run` in any case, but I don't see how this could  have stopped working  if it was working previously. The error message suggests that whatever shell `os.system` is using behind the scenes has stopped treating this as a single path and started treating it as a path plus an argument, split on the space between `Test` and `UI`.

Comment: That is strange.It seems confused with the space in the name. You could try `os.system(r'"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI"')` - I just encased the string in single quotes so that the double quotes actually go to the windows process execute.

Comment: ...um I'm assuming the file to run is "Test UI.exe"

Comment: Note that in the answer on the linked question, `subprocess.call` is being used, not `os.system`. When you aren't using `shell=True` on the former, these are very different things. `subprocess.call` doesn't try to do any kind of string-splitting with the default `shell=False`, whereas `os.system` expects everything to be passed in the local shell's syntax (which requires either quoting or escaping whitespace, though the details of how are platform-specific).

Comment: @tdelaney It is actually just Test UI, it's a shortcut that opens a google chrome tab and brings me to a certain page. I tried using your single quotes and then double quotes method like you recommended, but I still get the same error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: So its a program called "Test" with a parameter "UI"?

Comment: You could `from glob import glob;print(glob(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test*"))` so that we know what the acutal file looks like.

Comment: @tdelaney It is a shortcut, not a program, on my desktop called Test UI, when it worked a few days ago it opened up a google chrome tab and brought me to the page I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason, os.system stopped working consistently and subprocess.run or subprocess.call didn't work. I switched my command to use os.startfile instead and it started to work properly.

Here's the end result:

```
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI")
```

Answer (score 4):

We've recently replaced os.system with subprocess.run after a number of problems with paths on Windows.

For this example, you could replace

```
os.system(r"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI")
```

with

```
subprocess.run(r'"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI"',shell=True)
```

For Windows shortcuts I had to add the .lnk extension in the call:

```
subprocess.run(r'"C:\Users\red\Desktop\Test UI.lnk"',shell=True)
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion and got the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Code above is tested on python 3.7.2.  My code that works is below `subprocess.run(r'"c:\users\myname\Desktop\AD Explorer.exe"')` also works without the .exe on the end and with , shell=True

Comment: To get this working with Windows shortcuts I had to actually add the .lnk on the end `subprocess.run(r'"c:\users\myname\Desktop\Postman.lnk"',shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are using right command to execute a file, but the file you want to execute is not present in that directory. The error `'C:\users...' is not  not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file` occurs when the file is not in the directory path.

There is no need to write `.exe` after file name, but you must write the correct file name which is present in that directory.

Comment: The file I want to execute is indeed in that directory. The file name is correct, it is supposed to execute a shortcut that opens a google chrome tab that brings me to a specific page.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)